# For command not processing lines from a file

Tags: windows-8, cmd.exe

I dumped all the physical network GUIDs to a file via:

```
wmic nic where "PhysicalAdapter = 'TRUE'" get GUID > networkAdapterGUIDs.txt
```

When I try to read the file and echo out its contents nothing happens:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (networkAdapterGUIDs.txt) do echo %%A
```

I have tried `%%A` with `.bat` files and just `%A` when running on the command line.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image: http://puu.sh/6Geyn/c09d1ad079.png]

If I could get a simple echo to work I later planned to do something with the lines that have the GUID on them and omit/skip the first line.

I launched up a fresh Windows 8.1 virtual machine and had the same experience.  I am currently running Windows 8.

Comment: cmd tools used to have (and obviously still have) problems with Unicode output produced by tools like wmic. Try to do simple `type networkAdapterGUIDs.txt >fixed.txt` (I think `more` also works but I'm not sure) and then run your loop over the 'fixed' file. If it helps I will put this as an answer

Comment: Found out that I could skip the file creation and just pass the command into for

    `for /F %%x IN ('wmic nic where "PhysicalAdapter = 'TRUE'" get GUID')`

I'm still interested why I couldn't get it to read from a file though, although as you pointed out it could definitely be a file encoding problem

Comment: I just tried what you said and that worked as well : ) thanks. wmic spit out UCS-2 Little Endian, and type spit out UTF-8 without BOM, checked with notepad++ That was going to drive me crazy; would have never question the file encoding.  At that point I was sure that Windows 8 had some issues with its for loop file reading, glad to know it doesn't.

Comment: just be careful as you may also get unexpected results when running wmic directly from within `for` (its output contains chars treated as control by batch engine)

Comment: Yeah I've been noticing that I'm having some issues with the empty line it throws in at the end even though I have the /F option

Comment: `'wmic nic where "PhysicalAdapter = 'TRUE'" get GUID ^| findstr /r /v "^$"'` removes the first header line and keeps lines where not equal to a new line

Comment: This seems to work fine, at least on 8.1: `for /F "skip=1 tokens=* usebackq" %A in (``wmic nic where "PhysicalAdapter = 'TRUE'" get GUID``) do echo %A` (please replace double backticks with single)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cmd tools used to have (and obviously still have) problems with Unicode output produced by tools like `wmic`. Try to do simple `type networkAdapterGUIDs.txt >fixed.txt`  and then run your loop over the 'fixed' file

[Rob van der Woude's page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/type.php#Unicode) has also excellent section on those [conversions]